# Want to do some damage control

Tags: interview

I applied for a job in a company. The initial conversation went well.They sent me an assignment and asked me to write a web application, and send it in a specified time. It seemed fairly simple. I completed and sent it to them. Now my mind is completely revolving on the code that I wrote, and now I feel that, there was one small requirement which I did not fulfill. Before they give the verdict shall I be proactive and admit it. Definitely they will find it and I am certain of it. I can send them email saying that I forgot to add that.
What shall I do? Is there anything I do for damage control?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Honestly just forget about it. I doubt they will care that you missed one small bit. The purpose of the exercise was to ensure in general terms that you knew what you were doing. Keep applying for other jobs and don't get too fixated on this particular job.

Comment: +1 I agree, don't short sell yourself. It is an honest mistake, that's why we have customer acceptance tests. Be open to feedback if they come back to you with it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm all for being proactive and telling them about it. If I were the one looking at your code and I noticed an unfulfilled requirement, it would say something important to me that you not only realized the error on your own, but that you were willing to do something about it.

Answer (score 1):

Might as well admit you forgot one of the requirements. If you are certain they will notice, then you have nothing to lose. They might appreciate you being forthcoming about it and if they don't, then it's better that you don't work there.

Answer (score 1):

You are leaving out some pertinent details.  Was there a time crunch and that is why you forgot the item?  Did you just think it's a simple app and didn't take the time to write your design down before and reviewing it before sending it in?

What I'm sensing is too much emphasis on something that is already done with.  If you forgot something, let them know, but explain why with a plausable explanation.

Are you quitting the field if you don't get this job?  Do your best whenever you can, but don't let this slow you down or stop you.

I would express the truth, your desire for the position, hope for the best and move on to the next position if it doesn't pan out.